# watchOS NavigationSplitView with button to add to source list

Tags: watchos, navigationsplitview

I am replacing my NavigationStack watchOS root view with NavigationSplitView to confirm with the new design paradigm on watchOS 10. My app is very similar to the Weather app, where you have a source list of cities (which the user can add to) and a detail view showing the details for a given city.

I have the master-detail view set up, but the thing I don't understand is how to add other navigation targets than the detail view. I.e. the button at the end of the list should take the user to a new page where they can add a new city to the source list.

Previously this would be handled in `navigationDestination`; should I now simply have that logic in `details`?

In the Weather app, there is a `+` button at the end of the lists of your cities, which will not navigate but pop up a modal to add a new city.